# Bash. Using find and a for loop. Can't find how to mv file into the directory that was found. Just moves to root directory given.

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, mv

Current code.

Right now I have a test format set up.  Here is what I have.

```
files=`find C:/PATH/TO/DIRECTORY/2014-05-08 -name *.txt`
```

(I will be running this from C:/PATH/TO/DIRECTORY.  Just right now I'm only testing on todays directory so I don't change everything in /DIRECTORY.)  The .sh script is being run from /DIRECTORY therefore it is it's root.) In the implemented version find will look like this:

```
 files=`find C:/PATH/TO/DIRECTORY -name *.txt`

 for file in $files; do
 #code to manipulate filename
 mv $file $newFilename
```

The problem that I am getting is that this renames the old file name into the new file name, but the new files are in /DIRECTORY when I want them to be in the directory that the program is currently looping through. Which in this case is /DIRECTORY/2014-05-08.

I was just going to make a variable for the current directory of $file, but couldn't figure out how and use:

```
mv $file /CWD/$newFilename
```

but I was unable to find a way to assign CWD the directory that $file was in.  This would probably be the easiest way if it's possible.

Comment: What is `$newFilename` here?

Comment: sorry cant provide a solution to you, deleting answer

Comment: $newFilename is the renamed file name.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a better way to code that:

```
find dir -name \*.txt |
while IFS= read -r file; do
    dir=$(dirname "$file")
    file=$(basename "$file")

    newfile=...whatever...

    mv "$dir/$file" "$dir/$newfile"
done
```

Using a `for` loop over the results of `find` will iterate over the **words** in the result, not necessarily the **lines** -- if there's a filename with a space in it, the `for` loop won't get the right filename.

The `while IFS= read -r line` technique I demonstrate is the safest way to iterate over the **lines** of the result of a command.

There are other issues in my code that I don't think are strictly relevant here.